# liquibase sql migration issue

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, liquibase, liquibase-sql

I am writing 1 PostgreSQL function for some operation.
Writing SQL migration for that function but facing formatting error as liquibase is not able to recognize some portion.

Function Liquibase Migration:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.fncn(trId integer, sts integer, stIds character varying)
 RETURNS double precision
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS '
DECLARE
      abc integer;
      query CHAR(1500);
      xyz   integer;
BEGIN
      query := ''select sum(t.a) 
      FROM schema.tbl t 
      where t.id in(1,2) 
      and t.status ='' || sts || 
      '' and t.status <> 2 
      and t.tr_id ='' || trId || 
      '' and t.sw in('''', ''N'')'';

      IF stIds is not null then
        query := query || '' AND t.st_id IN ('' || stIds || '')'';
      ELSE
      END IF;

      EXECUTE query INTO abc;

      SELECT abc INTO xyz;
    RETURN xyz;
END;
'
;
```

Following error it throwing:

**Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "N"**

**Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "N"**

Any suggestion what I am missing?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oh sorry, I was not aware about dollar quoting, let me try that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: your suggestion worked like magic.. Can you please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem is the nesting of `'` of single quotes. To make that easier, use [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) for the function body. You can nest dollar quoted string by choosing different delimiters.

To avoid any problems with concatenation of parameters, use [parameter place holders](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) in the query and pass the values with the `USING` clause. That will however require two different `execute` calls.

I assume `stIds` is a comma separated string of values. To use that as a (single) placeholder, convert it to an array using `string_to_array()` - or even better: change the type of the input parameter to `text[]` and pass an array directly.

The query variable is better defined as `text`, [don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29). There is also no need to copy the result of the query into a different variable (which by the way would be more efficient using `xyz := abc;` rather than a `select into`)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.fncn(trId integer, sts integer, stIds character varying)
 RETURNS double precision
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$body$
DECLARE
      abc integer;
      query text;
BEGIN
  query := $q$ select sum(t.a) 
            FROM schema.tbl t 
            where t.id in (1,2) 
            and t.status = $1 
            and t.status <> 2 
            and t.tr_id = $2
            and t.sw in ('''', 'N') $q$;

  IF stIds is not null then
    query := query || $sql$ AND t.st_id = ANY (string_to_array($4, ',') $sql$;
    EXECUTE query INTO abc
      using trid, sts, stids;
  ELSE
    EXECUTE query INTO abc
      using trid, sts;
  END IF;
      
  RETURN abc;
END;
$body$
;
```

Note that in the Liquibase change, you must use `splitStatements=false` in order to run this without errors.